# typeorm migration:generate - Error: Unable to open file

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I tried to generate a Type ORM migration file with the `typeorm migration:generate InitialSetup -d ormconfig.ts` command, but I got the following error:

```
Error: Unable to open file: "C:\_work\template-db\ormconfig.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at CommandUtils.loadDataSource (C:\_work\template-db\node_modules\typeorm\commands\CommandUtils.js:22:19)
    at async Object.handler (C:\_work\template-db\node_modules\typeorm\commands\MigrationGenerateCommand.js:68:26)
```

I have the following `ormconfig.ts` file:

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import ApplicationConstants from "@config/application-constants";
import path from "path";

export const dataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: ApplicationConstants.DatabaseHost,
    port: ApplicationConstants.DatabasePort,
    username: ApplicationConstants.DatabaseUsername,
    password: ApplicationConstants.DatabasePassword,
    database: ApplicationConstants.DatabaseName,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: false,
    migrationsRun: false,
    migrations: [path.join(__dirname, "migrations/**/*{.js,.ts}")],
    entities: [path.join(__dirname, "entity/**/*{.js,.ts}")],
});
```

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

Note:
I don't want to create a migration file with the `typeorm migration:create` command, I want to generate it with the `typeorm migration:generate` command.

Versions:

- Node: 18.12.1
- Type ORM: 0.3.10

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my reason was because of typescript module system. I imported config from barrel files, so after I removed index.ts files and imported one by one it resolved. Also you can debug with Javascript debug terminal in vscode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need build your project first and then change `ormconfig.ts` to `<your_path_build>/ormconfig.js`

(I don't know why typeorm cannot read typescript file)